# Typescript: Updating Object

Tags: typescript

I need to update an object A properties with Object B properties, but only the properties which exist on A and B should be updated.

Now I am doing:

```
Object.keys(A).map((key) => {
            A[key] = B[key];
          });
```

I was wondering if there is a shorter version to do this in typescript.

Comment: Why use map as it creates a new array? Use forEach. And no, TypeScript has no shortcuts for this.

Comment: The code seems to update keys of `A` from `B`, which contradicts what you said about "only properties which exist on A and B", since, what if `A` contains a key that `B` doesn't, but the code makes me wonder if you've seen [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

Comment: This code would assign the value of those properties in object A as `undefined` that do not exists on object B.

Comment: Actually B is a Dto from API and A is an Object with some fields from B, so B always will have all properties needed by A.